# Autopopulate Django modelform placeholder with current project model name

Tags: django, placeholder, modelform

I wan't to autopopulate the ProjectForm fields with the current value of the field, i.e.:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    project_name  = forms.CharField(label='Project Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'fixed_value'}))
```

However instead of a fixed value I would like to prepopulate the field with the current project name (if appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the project/object within your view you could do it like so:

`forms.py`:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    project_name = forms.CharField(label='Project Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'fixed_value'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        placeholder = kwargs.pop("dynamic_placeholder")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['project_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = placeholder
```

`views.py`:

```
class YourView(FormView):
    form_class = ProjectForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        form_kwargs['dynamic_placeholder'] = 'dynamic_value_queried_by_orm'
        return form_kwargs
```

I am not sure what you mean by 'autopopulating'. You give the `placeholder` attribute as an example but maybe you want to use [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial) instead?

```
self.fields['project_name'].initial = placeholder
```

But then why are you not using an [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView)?

Comment: No I think the complex answer is the answer. I want to use the current value of Project.project_name as the placeholder for the ProjectForm.project_name field. I'll will try to get it working.

Comment: Okay, good luck. Please consider to give me an upvote and/or to accept my answer if I could help you.

Comment: I found an alternative solution by rearanging the urls. I.e. the hyperlink to an project now points to www.example.com/1/results/ instead of www.example.com/1/change_project. So the user now only needs to fill in information when he actually wan't to change the project information. I tried to use your solution but stumbled various problems. Maybe at a later time I'll get back to this but for now I'll leave it.

Comment: Could you consider posting the answer here? I am just curious how you solved it in detail. To be honest I can't imagine a better solution than mine.